# Using list initialization with new operator

Tags: c++, new-operator, initializer-list

**Background**

Consider the following code snippet:

```
MyClass * p1 = new MyClass;
p1->data = 1;
MyClass c2 = MyClass();
p2.data = 2;
new(p1) MyClass {c2};
cout << p1.data;
```

where `MyClass` just contains the single public member `int data`.

The first 4 lines are straightforward: we create two MyClass objects, one using `new` and one without. What happens on the next line is that the contents of `c2` are copied into `p1`, meaning that the output on the last line is `2`.

My question is about what exactly is happening on the line `new(p1) MyClass {c2};`. My understanding is that there are two operations: a `new` and a list initializer. For the `new`, based on [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/), if you call `new` with a pointer as an argument, it doesn't allocate any new memory and simply constructs an object at the location of the given pointer, with the pointer being the `new` operator's return value. This means that `new(p1) MyClass` resolves to a pointer that points to the same address as `p1`. Then, list initialization `{c2}` is used to set the contents at `p1` to `c2`, which is why the output at the end is `2`, and not `1`.

**The questions:**

Is this the right understanding of what is happening?

If so, one point of confusion I have is that the `new` operator `new(p1) MyClass` should resolve to a pointer, but it looks like we are assigning `c2` to it which is not a pointer, but rather a whole `MyClass` object. What's going on here?

Finally, I'm wondering what the motivation behind using this syntax is. I am new to C++ coming from C, and in C you would just write something like `*p1 = c2;` to accomplish the same thing as `new(p1) MyClass {c2};`

Comment: You are not assigning `c2` to the pointer. You are passing it as a parameter to the constructor - specifically, a copy constructor - which happens to construct the object in the memory that the pointer points to.

Comment: And yes, you can just write `*p1 = c2;` . There are situations where placement new is needed, but this is not one of them.

Comment: `new(p1) MyClass {c2};` is very different from `*p1 = c2;`. The first _constructs_ (by copy constructor) a new object in the location pointed to by `p1`. If there was any object previously, it is not destroyed (its destructor is not called) and its storage is reused. The second uses a _copy assignment operator_ of an existing object `*p1` and there is no object constructor involved.

Answer (score 1):

The question that you are asking has a variety of components to it. The main two things are

- The Rule of 3 (Big 5 if you include move semantics with modern c++)
- Memory Management

To start, when you use a **new** keyword it is used to create an object in the Free Store/Heap area by **allocating** memory and then constructing it. Objects created here remain here even after the program has been terminated and must be removed using the keyword **delete**.
With this logic the **p1** object is stored in the Free Store.

In terms of the first half of your 5th line

```
new(p1)
```

This usage of new does **not** allocate memory but does in fact construct the object at the location of **p1**.

The second half...

```
MyClass {c2};
```

is responsible for calling the constructor of the object and constructing said object based on the properties of c2 (Also known as a copy constructor.)
For a good example, here is the link to the documentation for the new operator in c++: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/

This idea of the copy constructor is part of **The Rule of 3** which are as follows:

- Destructor (Function called for destroying object)
- Copy Constructor (What is used in line 5 to create a new object)
- Copy Assignment Operator (Overloading the = operator to create new functions, ie Obj1 = Obj 2).

I recommend looking into these concepts to further understand object behaviors in C++. Most of these are already predefined for all objects in C++. However, you can always override any of them to fit your objects needs.

**Important Note:** If you override any of the default big 3 that C++ gives you, you must override all of them as there may be discrepancies.
Here is a good slide deck to help you delve into the topic of the Big 5 (The other two pertain to move semantics in modern C++, but the first three slide topics cover in detail the Big 3): https://www.feabhas.com/sites/default/files/2016-06/Rule%20of%20the%20Big%20Five.pdf

Comment: "*Objects created here remain here even after the program has been terminated*" - incorrect. When a process exits (or gets killed), its resources are released (forcefully - in terms of memory that's okay. Obviously no destructors for those will be called, but the memory will be returned). And please, do not recommend anyone to read cplusplus.com. It's obsolete and full of errors.